# Cannot use SSH Key Pairs for Bun.js https server

Tags: javascript, ssh, https, bun

From Bunjs documentation, the setting of the RSA key pair in order to use https is made using the TLS property of when calling `Bun.serve()` - see documentation here: https://bun.sh/docs/api/http#tls

The code snipplet is:

```
Bun.serve({
    port: Bun.env.PORT,
    async fetch(request) {
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({"message": "Hello world","from": "Paris"}), 
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                }
            }
        )        
    },
    tls: {
        key: Bun.file("./.tls/key.pem"),     // private key
        cert: Bun.file("./.tls/cert.pem")    // public key
    }
})
```

However, I cannot get to have the key pair correctly read.

1. for a RSA key pair generated with openssl `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256`, Bun throws the following exception: `error: OpenSSL BAD_PASSWORD_READ via OPENSSL_internal PEM routines`
2. for a RSA key pair generated with `ssh-keygen` , Bun throws the following exception: `OpenSSL NO_START_LINE via OPENSSL_internal PEM routines`. When trying to add start line and end line to my public key, the exception becomes: `error: OpenSSL BAD_BASE64_DECODE via OPENSSL_internal PEM routines`

I add that both my private and public keys are correctly formatted (with header and footer lines), correctly encoded and that the permissions (600 for private key and 644 for public key) are also correct.

I tried to copy/paste the keys directly in the javascript file, as string, and I got the following error: `OpenSSL BAD_END_LINE via OPENSSL_internal PEM routines`

Comment: The key length does not look to be the issue: the same error message with private keys of 1024, 2048 and 4096 bytes.

Comment: SSH is not SSL, they're not really related except at a relatively high abstract level. I don't know to what extent this confusion is reflected in your problem. Also, I wouldn't put non-SSH stuff in the .ssh directory, leave that to managed by and for SSH software.

Comment: Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk, this is a typo. I'll correct the text.